# Query para buscar por mes y año

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Uso VB.NET y SQL, ¿Como puedo hacer una consulta SQL para obtener los registros por año y mes unicamente? ya que generalmente las consultas normales se hacen por año, mes y dia, en este caso yo quiero buscar los registros de '2016-10'

Comment: Por tu pregunta veo que estas buscando datos del mes de Octubre de este año, tienes datos con esas fechas o es una data de prueba?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tendrías que comparar el mes y el año con la columna que guarde la fecha, algo como esto:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE MONTH(colfecha) = 10 AND YEAR(colfecha) = 2016
```

De este modo, con la función MONTH obtienes el mes y con la función YEAR obtienes el año dentro de la fecha. Así sólo te quedaría comparar con los valores que quieras (10 y 2016 respectivamente).

Comment: muy bueno e ingenioso

Answer (score 7):

En sentencias `sql` hasta donde se la condicional `where`va con `=` 
en ese caso tu sentencia quedaria asi:

```
SELECT * FROM COMISION where month='10' and year='2016'
```

en otro caso podrias usar rango de fechas con el `BETWEEN` como esta:

```
SELECT * FROM COMISION where (tu_campo_fecha) BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-10-31'
```

Comment: Deberías actualizar el rango de fechas porque tiene un par de errores: la fecha en MySQL se guarda con el formato yyyy-mm-dd (y no dd-mm-yyyy); y también tienes que tener en cuenta que si no indicas hora, al poner '31/10/2016' realmente estás haciendo '31/10/2016 00:00:00' y no estarías seleccionando los registros del último día del mes.

Comment: Pero la pregunta que el realiza es en base a SQL y no a MySQL

Comment: Cierto, pero aún así, todas las bases de datos guardan las fechas en formato yyyy-mm-dd y no en dd/mm/yyyy. Y el problema con el último día del mes seguiría estando ahí.

Comment: Cierto, gracias

Answer (score 3):

En si es fácil, si tienes un campo de tipo fecha puedes trabajar con el así:

1. Tienes un campo de tipo fecha supongamos un campo tipo DATE().
2. CURDATE(), que te devuelve la fecha del día actual según sistema.
3. las combinamos en la QUERY (consulta) y listo.

Paso al Ejemplo:
Supongamos una tabla llamada empleados, un campo de tipo DATE() llamado miCumple, ahora, lo que nos piden que hagamos es que calculemos los cumpleañeros del mes entonces hacemos la consulta:

```
select * from empleados where MONTH(miCumple) = MONTH(CURDATE());
```

Eso sería todo, lo puedes pasar a un Procedimiento Almacenado o lanzarlo simplemente así, ya que de ahora en más bastará con llamar a dicha función y en cualquier momento que desees tendras los cumpleañeros del mes, espero te sirva...